# Neo4j Traverse API vs Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

I am trying to verify if an image Node is connected with a group of tags.
The picture above shows my procedure code which can be called like this: `"CALL myProcedure(imageNode, ['tag1', 'tag2']) YIELD node RETURN node"`.

The procedure is 2x slower than cypher query: `"MATCH (imageNode)-[:has_tag]->(t:Tag) WHERE t.name='tag1' WITH imageNode MATCH (imageNode)-[:has_tag]->(t:Tag) WHERE t.name='tag2' RETURN imageNode"`

Why this could be happend? Did i make some mistake in my procedure? If there are too more tags the cypher query will be too long， this is why i am writing directly the verification logic into a procedure.

Any suggestions welcome, thanks :).

Comment: Please provide code as text, not an image. Also, you did not show all of your procedure, which makes it harder to advise you.

Comment: I will do it next time, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write a custom procedure. It is easy to simplify your `Cypher` query to handle any number of tags.

For example, this query assumes you pass it a `$tagNames` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) containing a list of tag names:

```
MATCH (image:Image)
WHERE ALL(t IN $tagNames WHERE EXISTS((image)-[:has_tag]->({name: t})))
RETURN image
```

Comment: Although it is no longer needed but I still desire to know if there are some problems with my procedure implementation. Could you help me one more time? Thank you very much.